# POST output into a modal from any form class on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Sorry I am a beginner with jQuery and Javascript.  I want to be able to get the results into my modal from any form on the page that has class ajax.  My code is below but not working correctly.  Currently it opens the post result in a new page and not in the modal.  Can anyone shed any light on my code?
Many thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.ajax').click(function() {
      var that = $(this),
      url = that.attr('action'),
      type = that.attr('method'),
      data = {};

      that.find('name').each(function(index, value) {
         var that = $(this),
         name = that.attr('name'),
         value = that.val();

         data[name] = value;
      });
      console.log(value);
      // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
      // Add response in Modal body
      $('.modal-body').html(response);

      // Display Modal
      $('#aaModal').modal('show');
       }
    });
   });
   });
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that would navigate the user to a new page.  Can you provide a more complete example?  Though it does seem strange that you're attaching a `click` event to what appears to be a `<form>` element.  Are you instead clicking on a button or link or something?

Comment: You are correct.  It is a form and was trying to troubleshoot as the page just does not open in the modal.  But the post result does output to the page rather than the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because your browser submits the form by default. It doesnt know youre doing AJAX stuff. To prevent this, use [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)().

In addition to that, jQuery has a built in function for serializing ([1](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [2](https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)) form data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('form.ajax').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevents opening the form action url
      
      var $form = $(this),
         url = $form.attr('action'),
         type = $form.attr('method'),
         data = $form.serialize();

      
      // console.log(value); // value doesnt exist outside of your loop btw
      
      // AJAX request
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: type,
         data: data,
         success: function(response){
            // Add response in Modal body
            $('.modal-body').html(response);

            // Display Modal
            $('#aaModal').modal('show');
         }
       });
   });
});
```

Also, its not quite clear if you bind the click event handler to a form or a button, I guess the first one. You should change the handler to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
```

Comment: Thanks a million Alex going to give this a go now and the bind was originally to a form but was troubleshooting with a button also.  However, with either I could not get the behaviour I wanted.

Comment: @Tone there are plenty, and I really mean plenty, exact examples of what you are trying to achieve. Just have a look at jQuery AJAX form examples.